# Dart wrapper over js library and use it in flutter app

Tags: javascript, dart, flutter, currency

Put it simple I want to make small currency exchange app (pet project- I want free API( 1000 requests per month including more currency is a perfect option)). I dont like the free APIs I have found so far but I have found this website https://bg.coinmill.com/ and I wanna use it for my purpose. Reading an answer to similar question:

> The only way to make use of JS in Flutter is using WebView.
>
> Dart compiles to JS only for browser applications, for Flutter it compiles >to native machine code.
>
> convert js code direcly to dart, using package js
>
> package JS doesn't convert JS, it just creates proxies for JS functions to >be able to call them from Dart, but that is also only supported in Dart web >applications.

Put it simple it isn't possible without hitting some compilation errors and some workarounds. However https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappbrowser looks promissing. Embedding the webpage that will look ugly and I won't have any control over ui/settings. My options now are looking for another free currency API or trying to find a workaround. I incline for another API, but not sure which one. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Why do you think you need JavaScript for that?

Comment: Well I thought it will be nice use case how to wrap js lib and use it. Just to make sure the quoted answer above is yours @Günter Zöchbauer. Otherwise I will get A nice recommendation. P.S. I think I tried to ask you in the gitter flutter channel about that and your advice, but in vain. Thanks for answering here mate.

Comment: Gitter is a bit difficult to keep up. I prefer SO questions. People usually make more effort explaining their problem/question here and it doesn't get mixed up with lots of unrelated comments. That makes it easier when jumping between different tasks. The webview plugin from the Flutter team https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/webview_flutter is shown inline like any other widget (still early stage).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically what you actually want to do is use that website to do the currency conversion in the background (enter value, press "Convert"), then display the result in your Flutter app? You don't need javascript for that.

After entering pressing the submit button, the site simply redirects you to a different page (GET request) with an URL like this:

```
https://bg.coinmill.com/CAD_USD.html?CAD=22
```

Use dart's `http` library to perform the same request with the right currency/value parameters. The result of the request contains the source code of the web page.

Instead of displaying the web page, you just need to read the value you need from the source code of the web page:

```
<div id="currencyBox1">
<input class="currencyField" ... value="16.46" ...>
<a href="/USD_calculator.html">САЩ долар (USD)</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, how I understand your question, you have some js library, and you want to use it from Dart?

If question so, yes, you can do it using Dart JS Intertop. The more information in the [link](https://webdev.dartlang.org/guides/web-programming#js-interop).

**Edit**

Yes, you are right, you can call js from Flutter only using `evalJavascript` function from `flutter_webview_plugin`.

Comment: Привет :) I want to use the result of calling JS lib functions in Flutter, but dart code in flutter compiles to native code not js one on one hand and on the second hand I think i can't call js lib outside flutter webview. Otherwise if I was talking about web app your answer should have been perfectly fine.

Comment: @speedyGonzales, Здрасьте. Yes, you are right, you can use js code only from flutter's webview plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firebase Cloud Functions and wrap your function in a callable function. You'll have all node js environment and Dart code will only call a function.